# "Les sessions grammaire et expression" -- is "grammaire et expression" acting like an adjective describing "les sessions"?

Tags: grammaire

> Alors j'espère que nos auditeurs apprécieront aussi la seconde partie du spectacle: **les sessions grammaire et expression**.

Is **grammaire et expression** acting like an adjective describing **les sessions**? Basically, this would be equivalent to saying **the grammar and expression sessions** in English. Am I right? I would very much appreciate it if you could give me some other very basic examples of how this kind of grammar works in French.

Comment: Is there a grammar session and an expression session? Or is it more like "les sessions 'grammaire et expression' " (in which case one may have "la session grammaire et expression") ? The analysis may be different.

Comment: I think it's both grammar and expressions in one single session.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, in a way, what modifies the head in a noun phrase shows something of the nature of the adjective.  Nevertheless this idea is reduced to a finer analysis the outcome of which is the existence of several functions. In this particular case the process at work is called "adjectivisation" ([universalis](https://www.universalis.fr/dictionnaire/adjectivisation/)). Here, you have a link between "grammaire" and "expression"; the two may constitute a unit (noun phrase) that is realised by the conjunction "et"; in "**I**" below we assume that this is so;  it'll depend on the context whether it is or not. The other case is considered under "**II**". The precise fonction (finer analysis) of this unit is not "adjective" though, but "nom utilisé comme adjectif en apposition".

**I**

"Apposition" is rendered through a particular syntax ([réf.](https://www.lelivrescolaire.fr/manuel/38/francais-4e/chapitre/382/fiches-de-grammaire/page/692773/l-apposition/lecon)).

1/ by a comma

- C'était une fille, une enfant perdue. (*« une enfant perdue » est apposé à « fille »*)

2/ by a colon, particularly for enumerations

- Ils lui demandaient beaucoup : faire son travail d'école, s'occuper de la maison, surveiller ses frères. (*« faire son travail d'école », « s'occuper de la maison », « surveiller ses frères » sont apposés à « beaucoup »*)

3/  by the use of a word called "explétif" (a word that works as a link but has not much meaning)

- la ville **de** Chartres – le mois **de** juillet (*apposé à « ville »*, *apposé à « mois »*)

4/  by means of a construction where the head is simply juxtaposed to the noun or noun phrase that has the fonction of "apposition"

- le romancier Victor Hugo – le Roi Louis XIV (*apposé à « romancier »*, *apposé à « Roi »*)

You recognise then that "les sessions grammaire et expression" is explained by "4/". You can consider that "grammaire et expression" is the **title** or **name** of the sessions; it tells what sort of session is being talked about. The general ajectival point of view is clear in the equivalent formulation "**les sessions grammaticales et à propos de l'expression**"; here there is not an adjective corresponding to "expression" according to the needed sense: "grammaticales" (French) say what the sessions are about but "exprimables" (French) and "expressives" (French) do not; in view of this we fall back on an morphological adjectivisation of "expression" (une session à propos de l'expression). Another form of "apposition" is possible, and you achieve the same effect (same meaning): "**sessions de grammaire et d'expression**" (n° 3/).

- (*same thing*) Alors j'espère que nos auditeurs apprécieront aussi la seconde partie du spectacle: les sessions de grammaire et d'expression.

You could also use quotes, but then you tend to  define formally the name of the sessions as a title or a formal name; you do so if you use upper case letters.

- (*same thing*) Alors j'espère que nos auditeurs apprécieront aussi la seconde partie du spectacle: les sessions « Grammaire et Expression ».

See [Termium](https://www.btb.termiumplus.gc.ca/redac-chap?lang=fra&lettr=chapsect7&info0=7.3) for much interesting information.

**II**

In "**I**" we assume that "grammaire et expression" is a unit; there is another possibility in which, through the context, we can deduce that there is an ellipse of "les sessions" and what we are given to understand then is really "**les  sessions grammaire et les  sessions  expression**" (or, again depending on the context "**la session grammaire et les sessions expression**" or etc.). This, clearly, is the case when in a given session you can treat either only grammatical questions or only questions concerning  expression.
There is no added difficulty in this case; the discussion is valid for each of the resulting noun phrases linked by "et".

Comment: I don't think it's an apposition at all. Appositions are set off by commas, even in French. It is an example of trying to reduce the use of sur/de or other prepositions. **French does this quite often and quite elegantly**. Here: les sessions [à propos de la] grammaire et l'expression.

Comment: @Lambie What do you make of this then: 'en linguistique, processus de transformation d'un nom en adjectif, généralement par apposition, comme " pilote " dans " projet pilote " '? (ref. universalis, in my answer)